# Countinuous extension to the whole space of a matrix-valued function $f : E \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose we have a continuous function $f : E \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$. Can we continuously extend this function to whole space $\mathbb C$ with range in $GL_n(\mathbb C)$.

I think by Tieze's Extension Theorem, we can extend this to a continuous function $\hat{f}: \mathbb C \to \mathcal M(n \times n; \mathbb C)$. But can we do this with the range to be $GL_n(\mathbb C)$?

---

My idea: can we just make $\hat{f}$ to be constant on $\mathbb C \setminus E$ with value to respect continuity. Not sure this is right.

Just to point out I mis-remember Tieze theorem, the domain must be a closed set. Anyway, there is a great answer below by Eric Wofsey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in general.  For a really simple example, let $n=1$, $E=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and let $f:E\to GL_1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ be the identity map.  Then $f$ cannot be extended continuously to $\mathbb{C}$.

More generally, there will be no hope of extending $f$ if there is a sequence approaching a point of $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$ on which $f$ approaches a non-invertible matrix.  But even $f$ can extend continuously to $\overline{E}$, there may be homotopy-theoretic obstructions to extending it to $\mathbb{C}$.  Specifically, if $f$ extends over $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ must be nullhomotopic since $\mathbb{C}$ is contractible.  For instance, in the example above, if you change $E$ to the annulus $1<|z|<2$, then $f$ extends continuously to $\overline{E}$, but cannot be extended to all of $\mathbb{C}$ because the induced map on $\pi_1$ is nontrivial and so $f$ is not nullhomotopic.

Comment: Thanks. What if $E$ is an closed disk? Will this eliminate all the pathologies?

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb{C}$ retracts onto $E$ and you can just compose with the retraction.

Comment: Thanks. Another quick question: if we have a closed disk $E$, and $f : E \to \mathcal M(n \times m; \mathbb C)$ with $f(\alpha)$ has constant rank $m (< n)$, I guess by the same virtue, we can extend $f$ to the whole space with image having constant rank $m$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  With a retraction, you can extend _any_ map out of $E$ to $\mathbb{C}$, no matter the codomain.

Comment: So by composing with a retraction, it seems we will not change the codomain at all?

Comment: That's correct.